# How to provide unique credentials for Set-Content calls

Tags: powershell, authentication, devops, unc

I have a powershell script that simply updates a file on a couple different webservers.  Each of these web servers have different local credentials that I need to provide in order to access the file in question.  How can I update my script to allow for this?

```
#message
$statusMessage = "hello world"

#servers to update
$servers = @("1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2")

#update files
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  Set-Content -Path "\\$server\c$\blah\foo.htm" -Value $statusMessage
}
```

Again, each server has it's own local Admin credentials that I need to use.

Comment: Why local credentials? Why not a domain account that has access to all of the servers?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart current/unfortunate limitation, the best I can do is have matching local credentials

Comment: Unfortunately `-Credential` doesn't work with `Set-Content`. (Run `help Set-Content -Full` - comment there notes "This parameter is not supported by any providers installed with Windows PowerShell.")

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this, if you really are forced to use local accounts (avoiding this problem is one of the purposes of having a domain), is to authenticate on the server using `net use`, copy the file, then disconnect. Example:

```
$userName = Read-Host "Enter user name for computer1"
net use \\computer1\ipc$ /user:$userName *
Set-Content \\computer1\c$\whatever\file.htm "Content here"
net use \\computer1\ipc$ /delete
```

Of course you can generalize the computer name within the loop. In this example, you will have to manually enter the user name and password for each computer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `-Credential` parameter of `Set-Content` doesn't seem to actually work (as [Bill_Stewart pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011669/how-to-provide-unique-credentials-for-set-content-calls#comment82994635_48011669)) you basically have 3 options AFAICS:

- Use `net use` to authenticate a session as Bill suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48013019/1630171), then write to the UNC path.
- Map a network drive, either via `net use` or the PoSh way:

  ```
  $username = 'Administrator'
  $password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
  $cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

  $drive = New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$server\c$\blah" -Persist -Credential $cred
  Set-Content -Path 'X:\foo.htm' -Value $statusMessage
  $drive | Remove-PSDrive
  ```
- Run `Set-Content` on the remote server and have it write to a local path.

  ```
  $username = 'Administrator'
  $password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
  $cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

  Invoke-Command -Computer $server -ScriptBlock {
      Param($msg)
      Set-Content -Path C:\blah\foo.html -Value $msg
  } -ArgumentList $statusMessage -Credential $cred
  ```

For both PowerShell approaches you'll have to prepare a [`PSCredential`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/) object as shown above, or just pass the username (in which case you'll be prompted for the password).

Comment: I like `Invoke-Command` provided that remoting is already set up.